# BOTO : How to retrieve ipRanges from a security group object?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I m using **Python AWS-SDK BOTO**. I m trying to retrieve all the security group details of my account.

```
secgrpList = ec2conn.get_all_security_groups()
ipRange = secgrpList[0].rules[1].ipRanges
print ipRange
print type(ipRange).__name__
```

But when i print the ipRange it shows nothing just two `enter`. When i check the type it is unicode. I even tried to conver to string **str()** but in vain.

What is the issue ? How can i retrieve the details ?

Please advice me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To loop over all security groups and print its rules including protocol, ports and ip range, try this:

```
import boto.ec2
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("eu-west-1")
groups = conn.get_all_security_groups()
for group in groups:
    print group.name
    for rule in group.rules:
        print rule.ip_protocol, rule.from_port, rule.to_port, rule.grants
```

which may result:

```
default
tcp 22 22 [0.0.0.0/0]
tcp 80 80 [0.0.0.0/0]
```

Comment: Thanks andpei instead rule.grants i was trying rule.ipRanges which was returning unicode, i still dont know what is ipRanges but i was looking for grants

Answer (score 2):

You might find the [AWS CLI](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) as helpful in this case.

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query 'SecurityGroups[*].IpPermissions[*].IpRanges' --output text
```

Or any other query string you need based on the reply structure: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-security-groups.html